# More elegant conversion of Postgres data within pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I have some data in a PostgreSQL table.

I am pulling the data back to a notebook via code like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

%load_ext sql
%sql postgresql://foo:foo@localhost:5432/barbar

result_from_sql = %%sql SELECT Date, Year,Score, Cost FROM MyData;
result_df = result_from_sql.DataFrame()
```

In the PostgreSQL table all columns were typed accurately but `result_df` is as follows:

```
result_df.dtypes

date          object
year          int64
score         object
cost          object
```

Converting the date column was fine:

```
result_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(result_df['date'])
```

As was ensuring all `None` values are now `NaN` values:

```
result_df.replace([None], [np.nan], inplace=True)
```

But to convert the columns score & cost to numeric I need to execute the following 3 lines of code:

```
s = ['score', 'cost']
result_df[s] = pd.to_numeric(result_df[s].astype(str), errors = 'coerce')
result_df[s] = result_df[s].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

If I use only lines 1 and 2 then the typing is still object - if I use only lines 1 and 3 then all the data is converted to `NaN` as if all the data has not coerced.

Why do I have to use this code and is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following solution to parse to numeric:

---

```
s = ['score', 'cost']

result_df[s] = result_df[s].astype(float) # incase you wanted to parse them to floats
```

let me know if this works

Comment: Hello marwen - this works perfectly - so much simpler than the convoluted rubbish I originally had !